# How to create Taxonomy Term using Services?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, services

I've a vocabulary called `Tags`. I need to create `Taxonomy terms` under this vocabulary using REST service.

So What is the JSON format to create `taxonomy term`. Similarly what is the JSON format to update `taxonomy term`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using POSTER plugin (for Firefox) to post data.

Here are the parameters.

**URL:** [your path]/[end-point]/taxonomy_term.json

**Content Type:** application/json

**Actions:** POST

Here are the JSON formats.

To create *Taxonomy Term*

```
{
    "vid": "1",
    "name": "My First Tag",
    "description": "Term description",
    "vocabulary_machine_name": "tags"
}
```

To update *Taxonomy Term*

```
{
    "tid": "14",
    "vid": "1",
    "name": "My First Tag Edit",
    "description": "Term description changed"
}
```

Here `tid` is taxonomy id and `vid` is vocabulary id of the Taxonomy.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: For anyone wandering the Interwebs you have to use PUT to update the taxonomy term.

Answer (score 0):

First of all tid will not be remain. It's always be incremental. You got the name, vid and description :).

You just have to use [taxonomy_term_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7). For more reference see [this comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/47038#comment-47038).

Comment: Sorry, may be I got you wrong. but I was not looking to create taxonomy programmatically. It was about to post JSON data to services to create/update taxonomy term.